# Can a single cat5e cable be used to transmit RS232 and 100BaseT?

Tags: ip, rs232, cat5e

Ive got a single cat5e cable running from point a to point b. I need to run RS232 and 100BaseT over it.

I know i can get 100BaseT over the cable by using only 2 pairs. But can i use the remaining 2 pairs to run RS232 using a DB9 to RJ45 convertor at either end ?

Comment: What about using all pairs, and putting something on either end (e.g. a RaspPi) with `socat` etc. that transfers the RS232 content over the network? Or, if you've RS232 USB adapters, `uspip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, RS-232 requires more than 4 conductors. Also, its signals only go maybe 50 feet if you're lucky, whereas 100BASE-T is designed to go 328 feet (100m).

There are "serial extender" products out there that can probably do what you're looking for. They convert the RS-232 signals into some other kind of signaling that can go farther over fewer conductors, and then re-convert it back to RS-232 at the other end.

Comment: Standard RS-232 does, but don't many systems get away with just RX/TX/GND?